# Is there any specific condition, When to use APIView and when to use ViewSets in Django

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework

IN Serialezers.py file I have seen, that the user is using APIView in one and Modelviewset in few.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.utils import serializer_helpers
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from .models import *
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import *

class ProductList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        products = Product.objects.all()
        serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProductSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class CategoryViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serialzer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ModelViewSet reduce the number of lines of code (which is tedious to read)

so using those custom ViewSet (you can even write your own to handle the need of your product), you can make it readable and not repeated code
that is linked with this concept, DRY (Don't repeat yourself)

[check DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

in the case of the APIViews, if you need an endpoint which does not rely so much on models, you can simply use that instead.